# C++ variadic tempates with default argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, default-arguments

I'm trying to write a template that will measure the execution time of any function:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void measure(const Func& f, Args... args);
```

I have a templated function with a default parameter `compare`:

```
template<typename T, typename Compare = std::function<bool(T, T)>>
void mergeSort(std::vector<T>& v, const Compare& compare = std::less<T>());
```

Then I try to measure the sort time like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 24, 7, 2, 8, 0, 8 };
measure(mergeSort<int>, v);
```

But getting compile error: `'Func (__cdecl &)': too few arguments for call`.

Running this:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 24, 7, 2, 8, 0, 8 };
measure(mergeSort<int>, v, std::less<int>());
```

all works as it should.
Is there a way to make the first version workable?

Comment: Suggestion: Make it `void measure(const Func& f, Args&&... args)` so that you can do perfect forwarding: `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); `

Comment: It didn't help. The same error remained

Comment: It doesn't fix the error. It's just a suggestion to improve the code a little.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with clang++ and g++) your error (calling `measure(mergeSort<int>, v);`). Are you sure you have included `<functional>`?

Comment: Yes I have included `<functional>` and `<algorithm>` even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the function in a lambda with a single parameter: `[](auto &vec){mergeSort<int>(vec);}`.

Also, `typename Compare = std::function<bool(T, T)>` is a bad idea, since the type erasure in `std::function` has some overhead. You should just use `std::less<T>` as the type.